# Trying to integrate user-made Bug Reports for TFS; issue with WITDataStore.dll

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-4, tfs, visual-studio-sdk

So from what I can gather online, to be able to save items to a TFS project, all you need to do is reference `Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client` and `Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Client`.

So, I run my code and have those files copy to my bin (because you have to get them from the Visual Studio SDK and reference them "externally" by browsing to the DLL).  When the program runs, it also copies WITDataStore.dll to my bin as well (which is in the same location as the two dll's above). However, when the site loads, I get the following IIS error:

> Could not load file or assembly 'file:///C:\SourceControl\pfSheets\pfSheetsOnline\bin\Microsoft.WITDataStore.dll' or one of its dependencies. The module was expected to contain an assembly manifest.
>
> Exception Details: System.BadImageFormatException: Could not load file or assembly 'file:///C:\SourceControl\pfSheets\pfSheetsOnline\bin\Microsoft.WITDataStore.dll' or one of its dependencies. The module was expected to contain an assembly manifest.
>   === Pre-bind state information ===
>   LOG: Where-ref bind. Location = C:\SourceControl\pfSheets\pfSheetsOnline\bin\Microsoft.WITDataStore.dll
>   LOG: Appbase = file:///C:/SourceControl/pfSheets/pfSheetsOnline/
>   LOG: Initial PrivatePath = C:\SourceControl\pfSheets\pfSheetsOnline\bin
>
> ## Calling assembly : (Unknown).
>
> LOG: This bind starts in LoadFrom load context.
>   WRN: Native image will not be probed in LoadFrom context. Native image will only be probed in default load context, like with Assembly.Load().
>   LOG: Using application configuration file: C:\SourceControl\pfSheets\pfSheetsOnline\web.config
>   LOG: Using host configuration file: C:\Users\rburke\Documents\IISExpress\config\aspnet.config
>   LOG: Using machine configuration file from C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\config\machine.config.
>   LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/SourceControl/pfSheets/pfSheetsOnline/bin/Microsoft.WITDataStore.dll.
>   ERR: Failed to complete setup of assembly (hr = 0x80131018). Probing terminated.

Does anyone have some ideas? Obviously, there must be more to this than I can find online, but I am not understanding what I need to provide to get this to work.  WITDataStore.dll is definitely in the bin folder.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, kind of old question but i ran in to this problem yesterday. The IIS must set the be able to run 32bit applications. Found the solution [here](http://www.tonicodes.net/blog/installing-and-configuring-odata-service-for-tfs-11/)

> you need to enable 32bit applications in the IIS. Open IIS Manager (via Start menu) and go to the Application Pools. Select the DefaultAppPool and click on the Advanced Settings…. On the dialog enable 32bit applications. I presume that you have also set the DefaultAppPool as the application pool for the service.

Comment: Hah, thanks.  Now to remember why I was even doing this...lol  Oh well.  Hopefully next time I do something with TFS I remember to try this if I am having problems.